# Selecting the first radio option by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, opencart

I'm currently using Opencart and I'm hoping someone can help me with this issue, I'm trying to have the first radio option selected by default when the page loads, I'm pretty sure the radio is selected however the button isn't clicked. I've been trying to play around with this code so that the first options class is changed to active on load as that's how the button changes color when its clicked however i haven't been able to figure it out.

```
< script type = "text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#input-option<?php echo $option['
        product_option_id ']; ?>') document.ready(function() {
        $('#input-option<?php echo $option['
            product_option_id ']; ?> span').addClass("active");

    });
}); < /script> < script type = "text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#input-option<?php echo $option['
        product_option_id ']; ?>').on('click', 'span', function() {
        $('#input-option<?php echo $option['
            product_option_id ']; ?> span').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
}); < /script>
```

i would really appreciate any help with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all the radio buttons with the name you want, and use `.first()` to select the first one. Then set its `checked` property.

```
$(":radio[name=yourbuttonname]").first().prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: i tried it but it didn't work, is there a way instead of having checked i can have the first option changed to class"active"?

Comment: Change `.prop("checked", true)` to `.addClass("active")`

Comment: tried that as well unfortunately still no change. here is a link to the page http://zipsigns.com.au/index.php?route=product/product&path=33&product_id=78 if you can see anything ive done wrong, when i inspect the radio element the .first() doesn't show up in the script

Comment: I don't see any radio buttons on that page.

Comment: Never mind, I see now that the assistance options are radio buttons.

Comment: The `active` class goes on the `span` after the button, not the button itself.

Comment: `allradios.slice(1).removeClass("active"); allradios.first().addClass("active");`

Comment: sorry im really hopeless at this, if i was to add that line in this script where would i put it < script type = "text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#input-option<?php echo $option['
        product_option_id ']; ?>').on('click', 'span', function() {
        $('#input-option<?php echo $option['
            product_option_id ']; ?> span').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
}); < /script>

Comment: allradios= $(document).find("#product input[type='radio']");
 var ter='';
 allradios.each(function(){
  tn=this.name;
  if(tn!=ter)
 {
  $(this).prop('checked',true);
  $(this).trigger('click');
  ter=tn;
  
 }
  
 });

Comment: i tried adding it there but it didnt change anything

Comment: That’s what the code was, I deleted it all and had all radios= your line of code

Comment: Is that what it was supposed to be?

Comment: Thank you for all your help, pointed me in the right direction. I ended up changing this line of code    “$('#input-option<?php echo $option['
        product_option_id ']; ?>') “. To this “    $('#input-option<?php echo $option['
        product_option_id ']; ?> span') .first().addClass(“active”)” and it finally worked

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, you want the first radio button option to be marked 'ticked' like the user had clicked it. If that's what you want, add checked="checked" to the first input or call .prop('checked', true) on the first input option element.

Comment: i've tried that but it doesn't change anything for some strange reason. here is a link to the page http://zipsigns.com.au/index.php?route=product/product&path=33&product_id=78  the option is the last one on the product do you require any design assistance